# How to convert a String in String Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am working on a login system on WPF and C#, and im taking the Input out of a textbox and checking if the input (username or else) exists.
I do that with:

```
string selectedUser = User.Text;
if (File.Exists(@"" + path + selectedUser + ".txt"))
```

then i want to create a text file with the name of the user.
i do that with:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"" + result + User + ".txt", User);
```

but it tells me that i cant convert a String to String[] (array).
And i searched the whole internet but couldnt find how to convert it, so i would love to hear a answer
from you guys.

Comment: Have you tried File.Writeline instead of File.WriteAllLines?

Comment: yup, didnt work.

Comment: Use "WriteAllText"

Comment: What is User? You are treating it as an IEnumerable<string>, And why would you do this by creating text files and not use a database?

Comment: i never used an database so i dont know how haha

Comment: But it is very simple. Just reserve say half an hour, reading the one of the simplest databases created for C# - LiteDb here: https://www.litedb.org/

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, I don't think he would be confused by learning this kind of stuff is meant to be done with databases. If he was asking it to simply learn File IO, then he could simply use a console application, rather than a WPF app. He could still learn it, and be better to learn from the start it is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, it IS the basics.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I would not call "basic" to database management, you can work all your life without even touching a database, if the user still doesn't knows how to properly write a file it is better he learns the true basics (vars, arrays, collections, file system, maybe networking, maybe UI) and then start with databases.

Comment: @Gusman, writing something to a text file is one thing that you can learn. Learning that saving your users to a text file is not the way to go is more of a thing but YMMV.

Comment: @CetinBasoz In fact, what makes you state categorically that storing a user name in a text file is "not the way to go"? Config files ARE text files and it is ok to store user names in there, or in log files, etc etc. And even if you want, you can consider a file system a NoSQL database...

Comment: @CetinBasoz No I'm not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netcore-3.1) method writes an array of `string` to a file.

```
public static void WriteAllLines (string path, string[] contents);
```

> Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then closes the file.

Instead, use the [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1) method.

```
public static void WriteAllText (string path, string contents);
```

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Comment: Thank you so much!! i just found out too haha

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: @MoritzBöhm, I mean, text files are not for things like this. You would be trying to solve database problems with the file system and sooner or later would face bigger problems. Using a database is the way to go. Be it a single user one or multiuser, very small or large.